# Cracking a PDF File using Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, pdf, cracking

I'm currently completing an assignment which requires me to create a script to crack a password from a PDF file, I already have a list which contains the password within, I am having issues when prompt to enter the path to the file and met with an Name not define error, please mind I am a novice to coding.

> ```
> file = raw_input('Path: ')
> wordlist = 'wordlist.txt'
>
> word =open(wordlist, 'r')
> allpass = word.readlines()
> word.close()
>
> for password in allpass:
>
>    password = password.strip()
>
>    print ("Testing password: "+password)
>
>    instance = dispatch('pdf.Application')
>
>    try:
>
>        instance.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, password)
>        print ("Password Cracked: "+password)
>        break
>
>     except:
>         pass
> ```

When the program is running, it attempts the first password from the list then proceeds to crash.

```
python Comsec.py 
Path: /home/hall/Desktop/comsec121/examAnswers.pdf
Testing password: 123456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Comsec.py", line 11, in <module>
    instance = dispatch('pdf.Application')
NameError: name 'dispatch' is not defined
```

Please excuse my formatting on this website, I am trying my best to help you understand my issue!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are doing `instance = dispatch('pdf.Application')` without previously saying what `dispatch` is. You have to define it first.

Comment: Would it be simple as just removing the dispatch? Sorry a friend helped me do this awhile back although I can't get into contact with them. I thought the 'pdf.Application' was inputted incorrectly

Comment: not quite. You have to use Python to open the pdf. Try googling that first. The code-thing comes second.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that inside your Python script there is no object or function with the name `dispatch`. You would get that same error if you tried:

```
instance = this_is_a_function_that_has_not_been_defined('pdf.Application')
```

Typically, this function should be defined in a Python module. To access it, at the top of your code you should have some import statement like this:

```
from aBeautifulModuleForPDFs import dispatch
```

That module will be providing you the missing `dispatch` function. Checking in Google, I suggest you to try with module [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). Install it (run `pip install pywin32` in a terminal) and add this line at the beginning of the code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch as dispatch
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to respond to my issue, however while trying to install the module, I am greeted with this message ..  pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32

Comment: `pywin32` is a module only available for Windows. I'm guessing you are using Linux. Do you have any info on the platform this code was developed for? Based on some searches, both the `dispatch` and the `.Workbooks.Open` seem to be part of this module. Can you try installing it/running it on Windows?

Comment: Hmm, I have recreated the code on windows was told C:\Users\THall\Desktop\comsec>dwdw.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THall\Desktop\comsec\dwdw.py", line 1, in <module>
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
ImportError: No module named win32com.client

Comment: despite pip install pywin32, I get this message again C:\Users\THall\Desktop\comsec>pip install pywin32
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\thall\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (223)

Comment: what about `pip install pypiwin32`?  I just googled your new error and found it

Comment: It's isn't working regardless, I'm now trying to try it again in python within ubuntu although Im struggling to get pdf file correspond to my password list, not even sure If Ive imported the correct modules... Do you know any guides for for using a list of passwords to crack a protected pdf file?

Comment: Nope! But you should reduce the problem to the minimum: If you already have the list of passwords, your problem is equivalent to opening one pdf file with one given password. Try to search how to open a PDF file wiht Python!

Comment: Ahhh Brilliant,! Cheers for the advice, Just finally go it to open the program, Now all i need to learn is for the program to try the passwords from the list ! thanks for your advice

Comment: Just a quick question, all tutorials I find regard zip files, I can find the extentions for the PDFs anywhere, got any pointers?